# How to check for a payment method on an AdAccount on Facebook Marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I get the following error when trying to create an Ad through the Marketing API:

```
error_subcode: 1359101
error_user_msg: "You need to have a valid payment method associated with your ad account before you can create ads."
error_user_title: "Add Payment Method"
```

I couldn't find any extra information on this *error_subcode* here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/error-reference, and the main error code "100 - Invalid parameter" was hardly any help.

**Note:** I'm not looking to add a payment method manually to an account at "...facebook.com/ads/manager/billing/transactions/..." to make this go way.

**Edit**: Is there a way to check if the user has a payment method setup on the Ad Account?

Comment: Not all sub-codes are documented; but the message speaks for itself, doesn’t it?

Comment: Naturally, it does. Like it says in my note, I know how to resolve it *manually*, but that shouldn't be the accepted way of doing things. I'm asking how to check for the payment method in that account, before I have to get to the point of having an error displayed (and add another bump to my error rate).

Comment: _“I'm asking […]”_ well, only now you are … // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account – properties `funding_source`/`funding_source_details` should help.

Comment: The problem description was merely providing more details to the question above, my intention never was to get a direct solution to the *error_user_msg*. I apologize if I wasn't clear, I edited the original text in response and I'll check your reference.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your reference, those were the properties I was looking for. If you want, please post it as an appropriate answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to check if the user has a payment method setup on the Ad Account?

Have a look at the Ad Account object’s fields `funding_source` and `funding_source_details` – using those you should be able to determine if a payment method is set up for the account (plus additional details, if necessary.)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account

Comment: While using `funding_source_details` I am getting the error
_Unsupported request - method type: get_

Comment: @AromalS did you note that it says, _"To access this field, the user making the API call must have a MANAGE task permission for that specific ad account."_ - and is that actually the case, in your test scenario?

Comment: User has MANAGE permission for the ad account. Checked using `user_tasks` field